# Коллекция List заполняется по два раза

Tags: c#

```
public class Data
{
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string AlbumLink { get; set; }

    public Data(string album, string link)
    {
        AlbumName = album;
        AlbumLink = link;
    }
}

public class Func
{
    public static List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAlbumTitles(string fileContent)
    {
        var albums = Regex.Matches(fileContent, @"(?<=name=)[^#]*");
        var albumsList = albums.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);

        var links = Regex.Matches(fileContent, @"(?<=link=)[^#]*");
        var linksList = links.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);

        foreach (var album in albumsList)
        {
            dataList.Add(new Data(album, ????));//ПРОБЛЕМА

            yield return album;
        }
    }
}
```

Я в коде пометил проблемное место, суть: мне нужно перебрать две коллекции `albumsList` и `linksList`, но если сделать так:

```
foreach (var album in albumsList)
{
    foreach (var link in linksList)
    {
        dataList.Add(new Data(album, link));
    }
    yield return album;
}
```

, то у меня в `Func.dataList` получается всё по 2 раза. Я понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что у меня цикл в цикле, но как сделать иначе?

Объясните, пожалуйста. Я уже очень долго ломаю голову, что-то не получается совсем.

Comment: `Func` я бы рекомендовал переименовать, потому что в .NET уже есть делегат с таким именем, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за заметку, переименую. Ваш ответ с linq тоже запомнил, пригодится, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понял, как у вас альбомы со ссылками сопостовляются, потому просто предположу, что альбому под индексом i соотвествует ссылка под индексом i

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAlbumTitles(string fileContent)
{
    var albums = Regex.Matches(fileContent, @"(?<=name=)[^#]*");
    var albumsList = albums.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

    var links = Regex.Matches(fileContent, @"(?<=link=)[^#]*");
    var linksList = links.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
    
    for(int i=0; i<albums.Count; i++)
    {           
        dataList.Add(new Data(albumsList[i], linksList[i]));
        yield return albumsList[i];
    }       
}
```

Comment: спасибо больше)) тупанул, конечно, знатно, забыв про цикл for